# Element out from container box that already fix

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of image that will show random quantity. I try to make every line with 2 images. But it doesn't want to split to 2 each line. but. 1 line 1 image. I already set the container to desire max width I will use and the max size each image. in  code i set max container i will use to 1024px. and each image 512px. i think it should not have problem. i already check with inspect. no padding and margin already. if i set it a bit low example to 509.5px. it will split to 2.

Here's the code:

```js
var caption = document.getElementsByClassName('caption');

for (var i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
  caption[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.banner figure {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}

.banner figure .caption {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 1024px">
  <section id="banner">
    <ul>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="banner">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">
          <figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px">
            <figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `css grid` if you want columns and rows

```css
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
 .banner figure{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 1024px">
<section id="banner">
<ul>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
<li class="banner"><a href="https://www.google.com"><figure><img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" width="512px" height="50px"><figcaption class="caption">banner</figcaption></figure></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
```

check this out for more information about css grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using display:inline so you might want to remove that and use:

```
   ul {
       box-sizing:border-box;
       list-style-type:none;
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
    }

    ul:after {
      display:block;
      clear:both;
      content:"";
    }
    ul li {
      float:left;
      width:50%;
    }
    ul li img {
      max-width:100%;
    }
    figure {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tazpdc2u/